# react native ios apps crash at _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow

Tags: ios, crash, react-native

My app have used React Native. Now have a crash as below

```
Thread 10 Crashed:
0   libdispatch.dylib                   _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 596
1   bee                                 _GLOBAL__I_a + 27144
2   bee                                 _GLOBAL__I_a + 29912
3   libsystem_blocks.dylib              _Block_release + 144
4   libdispatch.dylib                   _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5   libdispatch.dylib                   _dispatch_queue_concurrent_drain + 1384
6   libdispatch.dylib                   _dispatch_queue_invoke + 660
7   libdispatch.dylib                   _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 360
8   libdispatch.dylib                   _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
9   libdispatch.dylib                   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             _pthread_wqthread + 1288
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             start_wqthread + 4
```

Any one have idea about this crash? I even don't know when and where happen this crash.

Comment: Did you find solution? I'm encounter the same crash

Comment: Any solution? I'm seeing the *exact* same stack trace (except for lines 1 and 2 which only differ by symbol and address).